# create spaces in xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot 8760 values which consist of the number of hours during a year.

The problem is that I would like to configure the x-axis so it can show me better curves and set some marge between the values.

here is the code :

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(P2016, label="Wind Turbine Power")
xticks = range(365)
plt.xticks([i * 24 for i in range(0, 365)], xticks) # add loads of ticks
plt.plot(demand, label="demand")
plt.title(
    'Power Produced in kwh in france avec une vitesse de vent 2016')
plt.xlabel("hours")
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

and this is the result that I am getting: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w039z.png)

Comment: I don't understand the issue. If you take 365 numbers, and each number needs to be some 10 pixels large on screen to be readable, you need a 3650 pixel wide figure. If that is what you want, set the figure size to 36 inch.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
no, I am taking 8760 values (number of hours during a year), but I would like :
First, to make a marge between x values of 0.3mm. 

Second, to plot my values in order to get each day separated( 24(hours during a day) *365 (number of days during a year).

but I am not getting what I want that's why I asked for help

Comment: Ok, 8760 values, each ~3mm wide plus 0.3 margin. That would mean your figure needs to be 28 meters wide.

Comment: Is it impossible? 
otherwise is there anysolution to make the variable of the x axis clearer? 
you can take a look to the picture if you didn't